# Multiple Primary Key with asp .net mvc 3

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using asp .net mvc 3, and I have a problem with an entity that contains 2 primary key, when I try to insert data in the table.

```
 public class LineItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set;}
        [Key]
        public int LineNum  { get; set;}
        public string ItemId { get; set;}
        public int Quantity { get; set;}
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    }
```

when I try to insert I got this error :

> Unable to determine composite primary
>   key ordering for type
>   'ApplicationMVC3.Models.LineItem'. Use the
>   ColumnAttribute or the HasKey method
>   to specify an order for composite
>   primary keys.

May someone help me please !!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Assuming this is actually a composite key, since you can't have 2 primary keys... The error message tells you exactly what to do, namely add an order. You can do this by adding `[Column(Order = 0)]` and `[Column(Order = 1)]` to your key columns.

For your example:

```
public class LineItem
    {
        [Key][Column(Order = 0)]
        public int OrderId { get; set;}
        [Key][Column(Order = 1)]
        public int LineNum  { get; set;}
        public string ItemId { get; set;}
        public int Quantity { get; set;}
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I add this

        [Key]
        [Column(Order= 0)]
        public int OrderId { get; set;}
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int LineNum  { get; set;}
and the problem was solved

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;