# List View showing the same record twice when there are two record in the sql view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am a newbie to C# and have inherited a web app that I am now solely responsible for fixing and enhancing.
I just created a Controller and a view via the VS wizard "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework". I am using the default code that VS generated.

I also noticed that the record still comes up even if the ID is the same one as in the SQL View.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried to start over and build everything a second time.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JudgmentID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoanID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JudgmentAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JudgmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

> `1050001010    1000.00 7/5/2016 12:00:00 AM    Edit | Details | Delete`
>   `1050001010    1000.00 7/5/2016 12:00:00 AM    Edit | Details | Delete`

The second record should be different.

I get this error in a log.

SOURCE:System.Core
TRACE: at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)

Comment: I think you should fix the SQL to only return unique records, rather than expect MVC to filter them out.

Comment: Your view looks ok. The problem must be in the controller. Can you verify that Model actually contains the proper information?

Comment: @RobinBennett here is the what the query returns:
13017 1 1050001010 1000.00 2016-07-05
13017 2 1050001010 10000.00 2015-07-25

Comment: @the_lotus
// GET: VW_Judgments
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            
           return View(db.Judgments.ToList());
        }

Comment: @YosiPel put a breakpoint on the return and look if the value returned by ToList contains what you want or if it contains duplicate.

Comment: @the_lotus It contains the duplicate

Comment: This mean your problem is not in the view. You'll have to make sure your database returns the right values.

Comment: @the_lotus The view returns what I think it should. 
13017 1 1050001010 1000.00 2016-07-05
13017 2 1050001010 10000.00 2015-07-25

Comment: Show the code for both of your models in your question. Also show the query you're trying to run in the controller action. What you have posted in your view looks like it's coming from one entity. It also appears from your stack trace that you're trying to retrieve a single record...I see SingleOrDefault() in your stack trace.

Comment: I said it started working but I added more records as a testbed and it is again showing the same record over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
[Key][Column(Order = 0)]
```

and

```
[Key][Column(Order = 1)]
```

to the Model.

So the view would know that the Unique Key was the second column and the first was the PK from the in-joined table and the parameter passed to the view.

Thanks to Osama Aziz and Charles Owen for pointing me in the right direction!

I got my solution from verdesmarald's answer on [Multiple Primary Key with asp .net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962557/multiple-primary-key-with-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score -1):

this happens when you retrieving data from a database view and no primary key field, to fix it modify the view to select a primary key from any table

Comment: Osama,
here is the view  

select l.id, j.id as JID,  l.LID, j.JA, j.JD
from
LN l 
join JD j on l.LID = j.LID

j.id is the PK for the JD table.

Comment: Actually this l.id is the primary key for the LD table. What I don't have is a foreign key between them is that necessary?

Comment: You need an association between your two tables.

Comment: Do you mean a Foreign Key? Or something in MVC or c#?

I am using only one model. The view joins two tables in the database and returns everything the way I expect to see it.

I am using the default code from the index view generated by Microsoft VS.
This is the controller.

public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
    
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ViewBag.ID = id;
            return View(db.JD.Where(x=>x.ID ==id).ToList());
        }